# Filter arrays by specific character in it and by unrelated id DART / FLUTTER?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an API. It contains data that I want to filter in accordance with a special letter that is in it and by ID. Both models do not have a common ID. But I need  when it pressed the user receives data that is filtered by ID and simultaneously checks whether there is a capital letter A and a capital letter B in the name. I am trying to do this:

```
 List<Stop> stop = Provider.of<List<Stop>>(context)
        .skip(1)
        .where((element) =>
            element.stTitle.toUpperCase().contains('А') ==
            element.stTitle.toUpperCase().contains("A"))
        .where((element) =>
            element.stTitle.toUpperCase().contains("B") ==
            element.stTitle.toUpperCase().contains('B')).where((element) => element.stId == stId)
        .toList();
```

But it gives me the blank screen although status 200 from server and when I remove the line: `where((element) => element.stId == stId)` and it gives but when I remove this line, I just get solid data, not filtered. How can I resolve this?

The models:

```
Routes{
    final int mrid;
    final String mrTitle;}

 Stop{
    final int stId;
    final String stTitle;}
```

Also I was trying to do such thing and it worked with dummy data:

```
1. List <Stop> filtredstop = [];
2. initState(){
filteredstops = where((element) => element.stId == stId)).toList();
}
```

But in in my case it gives me not the array of filtered elements but only one item from array. So I don't understand, why.

Comment: I don't really understand this part `.where((element) => element.stTitle.toUpperCase().contains('А') == element.stTitle.toUpperCase().contains("A")).where((element) => element.stTitle.toUpperCase().contains("B") == element.stTitle.toUpperCase().contains('B'))`. For me, this doesn't filter anything. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Hi  @Valentin Vignal I wanted the data inside filtered by if it contains A ot it contains B in array and also filtere by id. But I don't get it how can i resolve this by provider.of

Comment: @inkwell075 , For the part where you want to filter and keep only the ones that contain `A` and `B` you should do this instead:
`.where((element) { final upperCaseTitle = element.stTitle.toUpperCase(); return upperCaseTitle.contains('A') || upperCaseTitle.contains('B'); })`. For the part where you want to filter to filter by `stId`, have you verified `stId` is not `null` or you actually have an element in your list that verifies `element.stId == stId` ?

Comment: Thanks for help, @Valentin Vignal yes, the stId in not null. moreover, I was told that each Routes has its own Stops. But the problem is that no matter how much I tried, I could not get the data to be filtered, because both models do not have a common ID. I know what to do to filter data that has a common ID, but what about the data that does not have one? I've already tried almost everything.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, 1. You need to filter existing list based on id received. 2. And look whether the filtered list has items based on searchText as you mentioned 'A' or 'B' and returns the final list ! Correct ? @inkwelll075

Comment: @Ragu Swaminathan Yes! Exactly what I have been trying unsuccessfully to achieve for two weeks now

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the list returned from the `Provider` is valid and has items.

```
List<Stop> stop = Provider.of<List<Stop>>(context)
```

The usage of `skip` operation may result in excluding the `n` items in the list. I understand you aware of that.

```
List<Stop> stop = Provider.of<List<Stop>>(context).skip(1); // Will exclude item at 0 index.


List<Stop> stop = Provider.of<List<Stop>>(context)
    .skip(1)
    .where((element) =>
        element.stTitle.toUpperCase().contains('А') ==
        element.stTitle.toUpperCase().contains("A")).where((element) =>
        element.stTitle.toUpperCase().contains("B") ==
        element.stTitle.toUpperCase().contains('B')).where((element) => element.stId == stId)
    .toList();
```

in the above snippet you are trying to filter the list which contains **'A'** in the title and the resulting list is filtered by checking whether it contains **'B'** in the title and finally you are verifying the **`id`** in the resultant list after filtering **'B'**.

> So the process is like below ActualList -> Filter('A) ->
> filteredAinTheList -> Filter('B') -> filteredListofAandB ->
> Filter() -> Resultant list.
>
> Here there may be chance that the list item title may or may not
> contain the letters 'A' or 'B' and end list for filtering with 'Id'
> may be empty.

**So the better approach will be first filter the list with 'ID' and then check whether it has 'A' or 'B'. Below is the sample snippet.**

```
 List<Stop> stopList = [ Stop('Avengers ', 1), Stop('Marvel', 2),
    Stop('Tony ', 3), Stop('BDE ', 4), Stop('JOE ', 2)]; // From Provider

  final receivedId = 1; // Dynamic ID received in the constructor 
  final searchText = 'A'; // As per your requirement.
  final filteredIdList = stopList.where((item) {
    return receivedId == item.id && item.title.contains(searchText);
  }).toList();
  print(filteredIdList);
```

So the result will output the following

> [ 1 - Avengers ]